# avoid displaying an empty column in a row during loop

Tags: php, mysql, row, isnull

I have this form that takes information from a live search form it then goes to another form to be edited if web owner wants to edit it.

As you can see the form has an Order Number column, when client enters a new order number for the same customer they do not fill in the 'img' column again the 'img' column is an image name and extension that links from another website.

When the web owner gets the information it displays all the information correctly but if there is no image name it displays the empty image box, I am trying to not show the empty image if there is no image name this is the code but unfortunately it does not work because it still displays the empty image box is there a way to not show the box but do show all the other information from that row?

Thanks in advance!

```
$ordNum = $_POST['submit']; 

if(isset($ordNum) === true){
    $name   = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE name='$name'"; 
    $qry = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
        $resName   = $row['name'];
        $resTable  = $row['tableName'];
        $resImg    = $row['img'];
        $resOrdNum = $row['orderNumber'];

        echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['SELF']."' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
        <p>Custumer Name:&nbsp;<input type='hidden' name='name' value='".htmlentities($resName)."'>".$resName."</p>
        <p>Order Number(s):&nbsp;".$resOrdNum."</p>
        <p>Tables:&nbsp;<input type='hidden' name='table' value='".htmlentities($resTable)."'>".$resTable."</p>";

        if($resImg == "" || $resImg == "0" || empty($resImg)){
            $resImg = "";
        } else {
            echo "<p><img style='border-radius:10px; margin-top:10px;' height='300' width='280' alt='orders' src='".$imgLInk.$resImg."'/><br /><br />";
        }        
        echo "<input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'><br /><br /></form>";    
    }
}
```

I know I have to prevent SQL injection Im still trying to learn php and SQL
I have changed the code to this and now it works but when it goes to another page to be edited..
NOTE: With the text below Im just testing if it works first.

The while loop doesn't work It worked for a while but then I started writing more code then it stopped working

```
    $edit  = $_POST['edit'];
    $name  = $_POST['name2'];    
    $table = $_POST['table2'];  

echo $edit.$name."<br />".$table;

 if(isset($edit)){  

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name='$name'"; 
         $qry = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql); 

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){

         echo $row['name'];
         echo $row['phone'];

         echo "success";
     }
 }
```

Comment: A `NULL` column in mysql (`img NULL`) does not result in a `NULL` value in php (`$resImg = NULL`), it is an empty string (`$resImg = ''`). Try `if(empty($resImg))` instead of `if(is_null($resImg))`

Comment: @Sean Alright I had used empty in a different way that's why it didn't work thanks a lot , I wasn't far off huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having trouble is because your checking for a null value, when your most likely not storing the value as "null". Try:

```
    if($resImg == "" || $resImg == "0" || is_null($resImg)){
        $resImg = "";
    } else {
        echo "<p><img style='border-radius:10px; margin-top:10px;' height='300' width='280' alt='orders' src='".$imgLInk.$resImg."'/><br /><br />";
    }
```

Comment: I fixed it it was the htmlentities and the Value '<--- too far apart --->'